# Convertir fecha del servidor a GMT

Tags: php

Hola buenas tardes estoy intentando convertir la hora que obtengo de mi servidor a GMT ya que estoy armando una consulta con la siguiente estructura de fecha **"00:00:00.000 GMT Sat Apr 09 2020"**.

Les muestro mi código que tengo hasta el momento.

```
$fecha1 =  date("M d Y H:i:s");
echo("Fecha servidor: ".$fecha1."</br>");
$fecha2 = gmdate("M d Y H:i:s");
echo("Fecha GMT: ".$fecha2."</br>");
```

Answer (score 0):

prueba con la función:

```
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01', new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Nauru'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP')
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php

Puedes utilizar la siguiente página para validar tu conversión.
https://www.epochconverter.com/